# Android captured Image uploading in server using Volley not working?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-volley

I am using Volley library to upload my image into the 000webhost.con server.

I am getting error:  "Error while loadin data!", Its not taking my image to upload into the server.

I don't know where its geting wrong? HELP..

Main activity: loadImage from camera

```
 public void loadImagefromCamera(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent image = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(image.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){
        //String fileName = "temp.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver()
                .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        values);
        image.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        startActivityForResult(image,RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

}
```

// When captured Image is selected from camera

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        cameraImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
        String fileNameSegments[] = picturePath.split("/");
        fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

        Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        //cameraImage.setImageBitmap(myImg);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
        myImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);

        uploadImage();
    }
}
```

API call for upload captured image to the server using volley

```
  public void uploadImage() {


    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://plantnow.net16.net/upload_image.php";
    Log.d("URL", url);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                Log.e("RESPONSE", response);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "The image is upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("JSON Exception", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Error while loadin data!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Error [" + error + "]");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Cannot connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("image", encodedString);
            params.put("filename", fileName);

            return params;

        }

    };

    rq.add(stringRequest);
}
```

MY PHP looks like this::

```
<?php
// Get image string posted from Android App
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
// Get file name posted from Android App
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
// Decode Image
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
// Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder

$file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
// Create File
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
```

Answer (score 0):

you have problem in you php file `<b>Warning</b>:  fopen(uploadedimages/) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in <b>/home/a6071050/public_html/upload_image.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />`

fix your php file then try again

Comment: I think the problem is in volley or camera capture. I couldn't able to find it. PHP, Yes its getting Warning but I have able to upload 2 images . I really don't know How they it get uploaded using same code.